# Java fast way to add and sort lists

Tags: java, sorting, artificial-intelligence

I have the following code for sorting moves in a board game. It looks to me like it can be highly optimized:

```
    private List<Move> sortMoves(List<Move> moves, int depth)
    {
        List<Move> sorted = new ArrayList<Move>();

        if (moves.size() == 0)
            return sorted;

        List<Move> primary = new ArrayList<Move>();
        List<Move> rest = new ArrayList<Move>();

        for(int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++)
        {
            if (killers.primary[depth] != null && moves.get(i).equals(killers.primary[depth]))
                primary.add(moves.get(i));          

            else
                rest.add(moves.get(i));
        }

        sorted.addAll(primary);
        sorted.addAll(rest);

        return sorted;
    }
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to the above (ie. intersect the two lists and return a sorted list)?

Note: The goal of the function is to remove the killer moves (primary) found in the moves list and then return a new list with the killer moves first followed with what's list from the original moves list.

Comment: `killers` is what exactly? Do you have evidence to suggest that your code is suboptimal (and compared to what?)

Comment: killers is a class that has a public property (called primary) of type: Move[]

Comment: So you aren't ordering the whole list? Just splitting it based on some condition that identifies two different "types" within the list?

Comment: One opt that I see which won't do anything really is getting rid of the primary list and just adding to sorted directly in your for loop.  Then just addAll(rest) at the end.

Comment: Another thing - what kind of List is `moves`.  If it's an ArrayList, then you should be ok, but LinkedList.get is not something you want to do a lot of.  You could also initialize your result array with a capacity to reduce allocations, but again unless you have evidence, this probably won't improve too much

Comment: moves is an ArrayList

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop, you may cache the value of `killers.primary[depth]` if it never changes during the loop

Comment: Could you replace List<Moves> with Iterable<Moves> as the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `moves` is not too big the current implementation looks ok. Its complexity is O(n). Only con here is the space complexity due to three extra lists viz. `primary`, `rest` and `sorted`.

You can save some space complexity by using `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`.

```
private void sortMoves(final List<Move> moves, final int depth)
{
    Collections.sort(moves, new Comparator<Move>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Move o1, Move o2) {

            if(killers.primary[depth] != null && moves.get(i).equals(killers.primary[depth])) {

                return 0;
            } else {

                return 1;
            }
        }
    });       
}
```

This doesn't use any extra space but has time complexity of O(nlog(n)). Additionally, its the implementation is concise.

**UPDATE:** Following is another elegant solution with no extra space complexity and O(n) time complexity.

```
private void sortMoves(final List<Move> moves, final int depth)
{

    int i = 0;
    int j = moves.size() - 1;

    while(i < j) {

        while(equalsKillersPrimary(moves.get(i), depth))
            i++;

        while(!equalsKillersPrimary(moves.get(j), depth))
            j--;

        swap(moves, i, j);
    }
}

private boolean equalsKillersPrimary(Move move, int depth) {

    return killers.primary[depth] != null && move.equals(killers.primary[depth]);
}
```

I've left out implementation of `swap()` for brevity. It simply swaps elements on the given indicies.

Answer (score 2):

To sort list fast try

[Collections.sort(List list);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

or

[Collections.sort(List list,Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: You should complete your answer by providing a Comparator that has same affect as OP intends.

Comment: More maintainable but not obviously faster